# RUN Powershell Script in Docker Container From Host Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, docker

I have a powershell script in host which copy some files and starts the container.

```
#Copy File
docker cp "D:\addApplication.ps1" website:/inetpub/wwwroot/

#Start Container
docker start website
Write-Host 'Process has started'

#Execute Container
docker exec -ti website powershell

#Run Script
Invoke-Expression "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\addApplication.ps1"
```

Second last command executes fine but last command will only execute when I exit the container session and returns error(File Not Found which is because it finds that file on host)

Question: Is there anyway I can execute the command in container session from the script. Or execute any command from script in any process(confused)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `Invoke-Expression` is not the correct command to run a script. You should use `& "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\addApplication.ps1"`

Comment: the problem is...when it executes the second last command it starts the container session and did not execute the last command until I exit the session...I want to run the last command in container session...not in the host

Comment: Then don't run interactively. Try `docker exec website powershell -command "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\addApplication.ps1"`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It worked...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use the `-ti` flags to start an interactive session, just execute the script directly via the `docker exec` command

```
docker exec website powershell -command "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\addApplication.ps1"
```