# How is it possible to run this PowerShell script inside a docker container?

Tags: c#, powershell, docker, scripting

I'm trying to run the below script (myscript.ps1) inside a Windows Docker container without actually copying the script file to the container.

```
$Source =  @"
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class Imagehlp
{
    [DllImport("imagehlp.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int MapFileAndCheckSum(string Filename, out int HeaderSum, out int CheckSum);
}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source

[int] $headerSum = 0;
[int] $checkSum = 0;
$result = [Imagehlp]::MapFileAndCheckSum(
    "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe",
    [ref] $headerSum,
    [ref] $checkSum
    )

 if ($result -ne 0) {
     Write-Error "Error: $result"
    }
 $headerSum, $checkSum
```

First, I have searched online for the answer and tried the solution in [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828162/run-powershell-script-in-docker-container-from-host-powershell-script) However, when I tried the given solution, I got the error below.

```
docker exec my-windows powershell -command "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\PowerShellScripts\myscript.ps1"

C:\Users\abc\Desktop\PowerShellScripts\myscript.ps1 : The term 
'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\PowerShellScripts\myscript.ps1' is not
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\Users\abc\Desktop\PowerShellScripts\myscript.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\abc...yscript.p
   s1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The reason for this error is probably because the script is in the host not in the container. Therefore, I have tried to save the script content into a variable in PowerShell and then tried to run the command with the variable.

```
$script1 = Get-Content ('C:\Users\abc\Desktop\PowerShellScripts\myscript.ps1')
docker exec my-windows powershell -command $script1
```

This time I get the following error.

```
At line:1 char:15
+ $Source =  @" using System; using System.Diagnostics; using System.Ru ...
+               ~
No characters are allowed after a here-string header but before the end of the
line.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedCharactersAfterHereStringHeader
```

It says that the here-string part of my script is not properly typed and there exists another character after  `@"` but there is no character after that. I'm guessing this is something related to newline or carriage return characters but I'm not sure. Can you please help me? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, I'd suggest taking advantage of `powershell.exe`'s [`-EncodedCommand` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-encodedcommand-base64encodedcommand)

```
# Load script contents from disk
$script1 = Get-Content 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\PowerShellScripts\myscript.ps1' -Raw
# UTF16LE-encode the script
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($script1)
# Convert encoded byte string to b64
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)

docker exec my-windows powershell -encodedcommand $encodedCommand
```

Beware that Windows' process API's limit the length of command line arguments to 8191 characters, so it only works for scripts of less than ~3050 characters (including whitespace)

Comment: Thanks @Mathias for the quick reply, I have tried your solution but I still get the same error. I have edited the post with the newer error. Maybe this error is related to saving a script to a variable and then calling the script via the variable. Is this possible?

Comment: @grcrtrkm Looks like PowerShell takes issue with the line breaks in the `@""@` here-string being `LF` and not `CRLF`, try ```$script1 = $script1 -replace '\r?\n',"`r`n"``` before `GetBytes()`

Comment: OK, now I got it but I had to call `get-content` with `-raw` flag to ensure that the script is saved into a variable properly. Can you please edit your answer like below. Thanks for the help, appreciated!
`$script1 = Get-Content -raw ('C:\Users\abc\Desktop\PowerShellScripts\myscript.ps1')`